# python: loop through specific key value

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to process following dictionary.

```
thisdict =  {
    "changes": [
        "abc",
        "cba"
    ],
    "projects": [
         "aaa"
    ],
}

added_change=thisdict["changes"]

for x, y in added_change.items():
  print(added_change)
```

desired output

```
abc
cba
```

Comment: Did you mean `print(y)`?

Comment: Also why try to loop over `items` when you have a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will take the error like this:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Because `added_change` is a list, not a dictionary and `items` is used with dictionary.

Your `added_change` list includes already `['abc', 'cba']`, you want to print them line by line, thus, you only need to use print with iteration on your list.

```
for i in added_change:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
abc
cba
```

Answer (score 2):

In the code you show, `added_change` is a list, not a dict, so it won't have a `.items()`. Simply doing the following should work:

```py
for x in added_change:
    print(x)
```